# Android Keystore Returning Different Hash Depending on Directory

Tags: android, facebook, hash, keystore, keytool

I have a strange problem with one of my keystores. Depending on the directory I am in, the hash from keytool is different. The other strange thing is that it doesn't ask for a password even though it has one. For example:

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias myalias -keystore ~/Desktop/Keys/mykey.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
QXK1vA...
$ cd ~/Desktop/Keys/
$ keytool -exportcert -alias myalias -keystore mykey.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
NqYlhGE...
```

Is it hosed?

Comment: does `keytool ... | openssl x509 -text` show the certificate in both variants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the SHA1 of your key, just type in

```
$ keytool -exportcert -v -list -keystore mykey.keystore
```

By placing `| openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` after that, you are encoding the output displayed by the keytool command. I suppose this is not what you normally want.

Comment: Hey, this worked! I was actually following the commands from Facebook at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-android/ but this gives a hash that works.